# How to render javascript files in all pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an mvc app that has multiples pages in it.
I created a javascript file and I added it to the head of my layout page.
Now when i go to some links in my app, the JS functions is not firing.
Let's say I'm in index view when I go to contact us a page , I have a button that calls a JS Alert.

Contact me page

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="JSalert()">click me</button>
```

And I already checked multiple post that are saying I should do this in my layout

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/myjavascript.js"></script>
@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
```

and then in my contact page I added

```
@section JavaScript
{
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")"> 
</script> 
}
```

I checked the console I have 0 Errors, besides when I put the content of "myjavascript.js" in my contact page, it's working fine.

I already installed and added to my web.config in shared folder

```
 <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
```

because I read somewhere that I should add this in order to get this working,
but still it's not.
Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: try putting the js file at end of body in your layout

Comment: I already did, but it's not working too.

Comment: Must be that you are getting something in the console. Also check the network tab when you goto say Contact page if you are getting a 404 for the JS file.

Comment: I checked the console again, when I click on the button I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: JSalert is not defined, but when I add the JSalert  to the view itself, everything works just fine.@GaganDeep

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `@Url.Content` bit for myjavascript.js. Try this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myjavascript.js")"></script>
```